# Does spring 3.0.6.RELEASE support Hibernate 4.3.11

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using spring 3.0.6 in my project with hibernate 3.3.2.GA. Can I upgrade my hibernate to the version 4.3.11.Final without any integration issues.

Comment: You can read details about it here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework

Answer (score 0):

For more information you can check

> Note
>
> As of Spring 3.0, Spring requires Hibernate 3.2 or later.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate

> As of Spring 4.0, Spring requires Hibernate 3.6 or later.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

in [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10839) there were some problems with spring 3.2 and Hibernate 4.3, and according to the issue, there have been quite some changes between Hibernate 3.6 and 4.0. And Spring 3.0.6 was releaded in August 2011 (but the issue is from 2013).

So I think you should upgrade your Spring version as well if you want to use Hibernate 4.3.

From one comment in that issue:

> Spring Framework 3.2.3+ fully supports Hibernate 4.0 to 4.2.x in its orm.hibernate4 package.
>       Spring Framework 4.0.1+ fully supports Hibernate 4.0 to 4.3.x in its orm.hibernate4 package.